# How to add loop in print template?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this print method:

```
print(data): void {
    console.log(data);
  let printContents, popupWin;
    popupWin = window.open();
    popupWin.document.write(`
    <html>
        <head>
        <title>Print tab</title>
        <style>
            table {
                font-family: arial, sans-serif;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                width: 100%;
            }

            td, th {
                border: 1px solid #dddddd;
                text-align: left;
                padding: 8px;
            }

            tr:nth-child(even) {
                background-color: #dddddd;
            }
        </style>
        </head>
    <body onload="window.print()">
       <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Šifra usluge</th>
            <th>Naziv usluge</th>
            <th>Datum dospijeca</th>
            <th>Iznos rate</th>
        </tr>
        for (let entry of someArray) {
        <tr>
            <td>{{entry.name}}}</td>
            <td>{{entry.code}}</td>
            <td>{{entry.something}}</td>
            <td>{{entry.something2}}</td>
        </tr>
        }


        </table>
    </body>
    </html>`
    );
    popupWin.document.close();
}
```

What i want is to add this loop in template to display in tr all data. Any suggestion how can i do that?

Comment: Use a components instead of `document.write`. That's the whole ideology behind angular

Comment: Bad idea to use `document.write`. Instead create separate component and use [ng-for](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html) directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
print(data): void {
    console.log(data);
  let printContents, popupWin;
    popupWin = window.open();
    var trHtml = "";
    for (let entry of someArray) {
        trHtml += `<tr>
                        <td>`+entry.name+`</td>
                        <td>`+entry.code+`</td>
                        <td>`+entry.something+`</td>
                        <td>`+entry.something2+`</td>
                    </tr>`;
    }
    popupWin.document.write(`
    <html>
        <head>
        <title>Print tab</title>
        <style>
            table {
                font-family: arial, sans-serif;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                width: 100%;
            }

            td, th {
                border: 1px solid #dddddd;
                text-align: left;
                padding: 8px;
            }

            tr:nth-child(even) {
                background-color: #dddddd;
            }
        </style>
        </head>
    <body onload="window.print()">
       <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Šifra usluge</th>
            <th>Naziv usluge</th>
            <th>Datum dospijeca</th>
            <th>Iznos rate</th>
        </tr>
        `+trHtml+`
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>`
    );
    popupWin.document.close();
}
```

Comment: i get an empty data...only display trHtml

Comment: try this now @None

Comment: now populates table but like this: {{entry.name}} {{entry.code}} and so on...its not getting data only this with {{}}

Comment: Any clue why is that ?

Comment: Solved , try now.

Comment: that's it ..tnx